# What does "transaction" mean on Azure Cognitive services?

Tags: azure, face-detection, face-recognition

Azure prices for the Face API in Azure Cognitive Services are determined by how many "transactions" were done. Currently it says $1.50 per 1000 transactions.

But this a really vague statement. If one uses their services for face detection and recognition in a picture, and it detects 50 people, and then recognizes each of these people, how many transactions are going to be charged? 2 or 100?

Answer (score 4):

> Each API call is counted as a single transaction.

Extracted directly from the oficial website:

https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/pricing

Comment: Keep in mind that for batch API calls (such as [for Text analytics](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-apps-text-analytics/#batch-apis)) each record passed is considered a transaction.

Answer (score 1):

AS per [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/face-api/) official documentation for **Face API**,

For operations that enable training at million-scale (available beginning March 1, 2018), a transaction is counted for every 1,000 images trained. “LargePersonGroup – Train” and “LargeFaceList – Train” belong to this category. Each operation in this category is rounded up to the nearest increment of 1,000 images. For example, a “LargeFaceList – Train” operation that includes 849,500 images will be counted as 850 transactions.

For all other operations, each API call will be counted as a transaction.